# Why doesn't Horizontal scrollbar visible all the time <table>

Tags: jquery, css

https://libbyhealth.com/%d7%94%d7%a0%d7%97%d7%95%d7%aa-%d7%95%d7%9e%d7%91%d7%a6%d7%a2%d7%99%d7%9d/

In this page,There is a table. On mobile view I wanted to add a horizontal scrollbar indicator, So that people can understand that is horizontally scrollable. I added, `overflow-x: scroll` on my table but it doesn't work.
It only shows the indecator on the bottom whenever it scroll. But cant able to show that indecator all the time.

Comment: That's the normal behavior of the scroller. You'll have to implement your own scroller at the top or where ever you want to place it and then scroll the table when someone scrolls it

Answer (score 0):

It is at the bottom because of the height of that table. If you set the height to like 500px and change your `overflow-x: scroll` to `overflow: scroll` you will see a scroll bar to scroll up and down, as well as a scroll bar to scroll left and right. But thats actually not a good way.

I would recommend to think of a diffrent way of indicating that people can scroll. Maybe changing the table itself (diffrent type of table, smaller font size, etc.)